# Pandas: ignore spaces in last column of csv when converting to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a csv file to a Pandas dateframe. The csv file has the following format (first line is header):

```
id,link,domain,subdomain,subsubdomain,difficulty,solved_date,instruction
0,https://www.example.com,Practice,Tutorials,dummyText,Easy,2021-11-01 14:18:51,'instructions\Day 0 - Hello, World.pdf'
```

When I convert it into a dataframe using `df = pandas.read_csv(csv_filename, index_col=0, delimiter=',')`, I get (some columns ommitted because they are not relevant):
|   | id | link | domain | ... | solved_date | instruction |
| -- | -- | ---- | ------ | --- | ----------- | ----------- |
| 0 | https://www.example.com | Practice | ... | 2021-11-01 14:18:51 | 'instructions\Day 0 - Hello | World.pdf
| 0 | https://www.example.com | Practice | ... | 2021-11-01 14:18:51 | 'instructions\Day 1 - Datatypes.pdf

It fails to convert lines with additional whitespaces correctly (the filenames are in apostrophes ('). Additionally, the column names are off by one. I tried ommiting the index_col option but nothing changed.

Does someone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to declare the quoting character to be a simple quote, because by default it is supposed to be a double quote:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(csv_filename, index_col=0, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")
```

Comment: This works but now my header is splitted into two header rows (one for everything but id and the other only for id).